# Merging Columns within the same dataset with R

Tags: r

I have a data set like the following:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

I would like to keep 3 columns and add the other 6 columns under the first three columns like this:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
n <- 3
do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(df1, f = gl(
  n = n, k = n, length = ncol(df1)
)), setNames, nm = names(df1)[1:n]))
#  a b c
#1 1 2 3
#2 4 5 6
#3 7 8 9
```

**Explaination**

The first step is to split your data a long every three columns. We use `split.default()` in combination with `gl()` for this task. `gl()` defines the grouping.

```
gl(n = n, k = n, length = ncol(df1))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
#Levels: 1 2 3
```

The result of `split.default` is a list

```
split.default(df1, f = gl(n = n, k = n, length = ncol(df1)))
#$`1`
#  a b c
#1 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#  d e f
#1 4 5 6
#
#$`3`
#  g h i
#1 7 8 9
```

In order to use `rbind`, the columns must have the same names. Hence, I use `lapply()` and `setNames` to rename all columns to be `names(df1)[1:n]`, i.e.

```
lapply(split.default(df1, f = gl(n = n, 
                                 k = n,
                                 length = ncol(df1))), 
       setNames, nm = names(df1)[1:n])
```

Finally we call `do.call(rbind, ...)` to combine the three datasets into one.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = 1L, b = 2L, c = 3L, d = 4L, e = 5L, f = 6L, 
    g = 7L, h = 8L, i = 9L), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```